# height min-content not working inside table (chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I want a table of fixed height where each row takes only as much height as is required by its content. And the last row inside the table to take up all the remaining space. However, the entire table height is divided equally amongst the rows.

**Note: I can't used fixed height for table rows as the content is going to be dynamic and multi line**

Here's what I have done:

```html
<html>
  <style>
    table {
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 1.5;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
  </style>
<body>
  <table style="height: 500px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Sr</td>
        <td>Name</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr style="height: min-content;"><td>1</td><td>Jack</td></tr>
      <tr style="height: min-content;"><td>2</td><td>Joe</td></tr>
      <tr style="height: auto;"><td>3</td> <td>Jim</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I expect the height of first 2 rows to be 18px each and all the remaining height should go to the third row. However, the entire table body height is divided equally amongst the three rows.

Tested on:
Chromium: Version 107.0.5263.0 (Developer Build) (arm64)
Chrome: Version 113.0.5672.126 (Official Build) (arm64)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick, remove the inline css in the first two table-rows and then changed the value of the third table-row to 100% instead of auto. In this way, the last row will get all the available height.

```html
<html>
  <style>
    table {
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 1.5;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
  </style>
<body>
  <table cellpadding="5" border="1" style="height: 500px; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Sr</td>
        <td>Name</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>Jack</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td><td>Joe</td></tr>
      <tr style="height: 100%;"><td>3</td> <td>Jim</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```